# Adding new cells in a particular position in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin

I just started learning iOS programming and have a requirement where the user is able to edit their profile (adding emails, numbers , etc). I wanted to do it like how the native Contacts app of iOS7+ does for adding new contacts. You see a cell saying "add phone" and when you tap it you get a new cell just above it. as you tap the "add phone" cell you get new cells piling up above. Can anyone point me in  the right direction to achieve similar results. Thanks for any help in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's a few different ways to insert a cell into a table view. You can add cells in an animated fashion using the table's insertion style in the table view's editing modes.

It may be easier to just add an entry to your data source array at the desired index and call [tableView reloadData]

For example if the add phone button was the last cell in the table:

in didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
if (indexPath.row == mutableArray.count - 1) {
  // Clicked add phone button
  [mutableArray addObject:/*phone cell placeholder*/ atIndex:mutableArray.count - 1];
  tableView reloadData];
}
```

After your table view reloads, there will be a new cell above the last cell where you can add a text field to enter a phone number.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add that cell's data in your data source and call reload ...a simple one.

for showing delete or insert button you need to use

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (<condition>) {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert;
    }
    else {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;

    }
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}
```

for action specific to rows you can use following methods

```
- (void)insertRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation;
- (void)deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation;
- (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(3_0);
- (void)moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);
```